# Unable to find user Id in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on small app which fetch data from film API and load on the page. I am using Router 6.8 but I can load all films required data from the API but when I clink the specific film it does not show the film detail. My main routes are on the `Main` component. Nested route of film is in the `Films` component.

Films.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NavLink, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Film } from "../Film/Film";
import "./films.css";

export const Films = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="results">
        <h2>Film List</h2>

        {list.length === 0 && <p>No films...</p>}
        {list.map((film, index) => (
          <p key={film.title}>
            <NavLink
              to={`/films/${index + 1}`}
              className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "activeLink" : "none")}
            >
              {film.title}
            </NavLink>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="details">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/films/:id" element={<Film findFilm={findFilm} />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Film.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

export const Film = ({ findFilm }) => {
  const [film, setFilm] = useState(null);
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilm(findFilm(id));
  }, [findFilm, id]);

  let details = (
    <>
      <p>{film && film.title}</p>
      <p>{film && film.release_date}</p>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Film Details</h2>
      {film && details}
    </>
  );
};
```

Main.js

```
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Films } from "../Films/Films";
import { Person } from "../Person/Person";

export const Main = (props) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="mainContent">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/films" element={<Films />}></Route>
        <Route path="/planets" element={<Planets />}></Route>

        <Route path="/people" element={<People list={people} />}>
          <Route path="/people/:id" element={<Person list={people} />} />

          {/* Person is passed prop with fetch results */}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This `Main` component is being renderderd in `App.js`. After fetching data from the API when I click on the film name it does not display the film detail. I am facing error unmatched routes.